# Excel merging docs macro

Tags: vba, excel

So, I have no coding experience and I have never learnt to code but I was able to stumble along this code here, I simply want to add an if statement to make it so I can filter out any documents not containing certain text in field A1. How could I go about doing this?

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then
        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1
                    wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                Next
                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work - make sure to replace **Your text here** with the text you expect to appear in A1.

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

        If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    countSheets = countSheets + 1

                    If wksCurSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Your text here" Then

                        wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)

                    End If

                Next
                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Procesed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do so:

```
For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
     If wksCurSheet.Range("A1").Value = "CopyThisOneToo" Then
         countSheets = countSheets + 1
         wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
     Else
         countSkippedSheets = countSkippedSheets + 1
     End If
Next
```

Change `"CopyThisOneToo"` according to your needs. For partial match you can use `InStr` or `Left` or `Right`, e.g.

```
If Left(wksCurSheet.Range("A1").Value, 6) = "Report" Then ....
```

You will need to declare and initialize `countSkippedSheets`, and you can include it in the final status printout.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub MergeExcelFiles()
    Dim fnameList As Variant, fnameCurFile As Variant
    Dim countFiles As Integer, countSheets As Integer
    Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wbkCurBook As Workbook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook

    fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

    If vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList) Then
        If UBound(fnameList) > 0 Then
            countFiles = 0
            countSheets = 0

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

            Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

            For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
                countFiles = countFiles + 1
                Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)
                For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                    If wksCurSheet.Range("A1").Value = "foo" Then
                        countSheets = countSheets + 1
                        wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
                    End If
                Next
                wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

            MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the changes made to your variable declaration, too.